# Any API to get the list of pokemon details

Tags: api, pokeapi

Now I am currently building pokedex app.

But I am wondering if there is any API to get the list of pokemon details.

Now my current code to fetch the details of pokemons are here.

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151');
      const { results } = await response.json();
      const detailResponse = await Promise.all(results.map(async ({url}: {url: string}) => await fetch(url)));
      const pokemon = await Promise.all(detailResponse.map(item => item.json()));
      console.log(pokemon);
}
```

Because https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151 this api only returns the pair of name and url at first.

Please let me know if there is one to fetch all the details in one time.

Also, are there any apis to return 3d pokemon images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the URL for 3D images for each pokemon.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/home/1.png.

Hope this will be a little help for you.

Thank you.